# loop parsing with pyparsing

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

There is a loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < pathTransform.Length; i++) {
        if (pathTransform [i] != transform && pathTransform[i].gameObject.name != "check") {
            nodes.Add (pathTransform[i]);
        }
    }
```

or as string:

```
string = str('for (int i = 1; i < pathTransform.Length; i++) { if (pathTransform [i] != transform && pathTransform[i].gameObject.name != "check") { nodes.Add (pathTransform[i]); } }')
```

Trying to write a parser for loops.

```
import pyparsing as pp

pp_cycle_start = pp.Keyword("for") 

pp_lpar, pp_rpar, pp_lcbr, pp_rсbr  = map(pp.Suppress, "(){}")  # left and right brackets

pp_cycle_declaration = pp_cycle_start + pp_lpar + pp.SkipTo(pp_rpar) + pp_rpar  # (int i = 0; ...; ...)

pp_cycle_body = pp_lcbr + pp.SkipTo(pp_rсbr) + pp_rсbr  # body

pp_cycle_parse = pp_cycle_declaration + pp_cycle_body  # final parser
```

But if the body has "if" or other cycles, then SkipTo () will only work until the first "right brace".

```
>>> print(pp_cycle_parse.searchString(string).asList())
<<< [['for', 
      'int i = 1; i < pathTransform.Length; i++', 
      'if (pathTransform [i] != transform && pathTransform[i].gameObject.name != "check") {                nodes.Add (pathTransform[i]);            ']]
```

There is an idea to make SkipTo ("right brace") for every "left brace", but I can not imagine how.

Comment: `SkipTo` is going to be a tough way to go on unstructured source code like this. For instance, if you see `for(int i = 0; i < get_max_len(); i++) {...etc...}` the ')' of the function call will be erroneously matched with the opening '(' of the for statement. Are you parsing C code? Look at the oc.py C subset parser on the pyparsing wiki Examples page.

Comment: (To answer your question, you *could* do `nestedExpr('{', '}')`, but this will just give you a big nested list of strings. You could wrap it in `originalTextFor` and then reparse the contents, but then you might as well just parse for the contents in the first place.)